# DrawerLayout, NavigationView, and android:Theme.Material.Light not compatible?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, navigationview

I'm trying an experiment, for the first time not using `AppCompatActivity` and using the new Material themes. I have no need or desire for backwards compatibility in this particular app, so am building for **Marshmallow**.

The intent is for the initial Activity to have an `actionbar` with the navigation menu on the left like works fine in `AppCompat`.  However, after setting basic theme stuff up to no longer use `AppCompat` themes, changing layouts, and trying to crank up the main activity, an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` occurs after the activity's `onCreate()` method is finished.  The exception happens during the intialization of an internal class `android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView`.

The same exception happens whether the `NavigationView` and related menu are defined in XML, or added programmatically. So I'm pretty sure whatever is wrong is related to the new Material theme and not using `AppCompat` stuff.

Has anyone else run into this? Should this work, or am I just being dumb?

Here are some snippets:
App style with almost all customizations removed:

```
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

activity_main layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <include layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- comment Nav view out and activity starts fine, with no menu of course -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Sample Main Activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    toggle.syncState();

    /* uncomment this if XML has its view def removed, same exception results either way
    NavigationView navigationView = new NavigationView(this);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    navigationView.setLayoutParams(new DrawerLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.START));
    navigationView.setFitsSystemWindows(true);
    navigationView.inflateMenu(R.menu.activity_main_drawer);
    drawer.addView(navigationView);
    */
}
...
```

I debugged into the `View.java` code and related `TypedArray` code and can see where its failing trying to process attributes while building the internal menu item class. It smells like a bug, but this is the first time I've tried not using `AppCompat` themes and `AppCompatActivity`.  I've also tried using the `NoActionBar` variant of this theme and adding my own toolbar, but that makes no difference, same error.

Any ideas/thoughts?  Thanks in advance.  Lemme know if I've omitted useful info, I'm an SO newbie

finally, here is the giant call stack. The root cause is the third exception in the stack:

```
06-10 14:49:53.763 30675-30675/test E/Cause: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NormalViewHolder.<init>(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:278)
    at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:379)
    at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:328)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5482)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4707)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4617)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1994)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1390)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1353)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:574)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3028)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:2625)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.onMeasure(NavigationView.java:223)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1104)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:446)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
06-10 14:49:55.023 30675-30675/test E/Cause: null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NormalViewHolder.<init>(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:278)
    at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:379)
    at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:328)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5482)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4707)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4617)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1994)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1390)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1353)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:574)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3028)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:2625)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.onMeasure(NavigationView.java:223)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1104)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:446)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
06-10 14:49:56.083 30675-30675/test E/Cause: length=522; index=540
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=522; index=540
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getValueAt(TypedArray.java:1132)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:661)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3964)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:573)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:569)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutCompat.<init>(LinearLayoutCompat.java:148)
    at android.support.design.internal.ForegroundLinearLayout.<init>(ForegroundLinearLayout.java:56)
    at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView.<init>(NavigationMenuItemView.java:64)
    at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuItemView.<init>(NavigationMenuItemView.java:60)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NormalViewHolder.<init>(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:278)
    at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:379)
    at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:328)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5482)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4707)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4617)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1994)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1390)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1353)
    at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:574)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3028)
    at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:2625)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.onMeasure(NavigationView.java:223)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1104)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:446)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
    at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AppCompat components (such as DrawerLayout), then you'll need to use the AppCompat theme as your base theme, and AppCompatActivity as your base activity.  The reason for this is that these components have a lot of references to support library methods and styles, so excluding them is not an option.

If you're worried about your app looking Material, don't be, these support libraries were designed to keep your app looking material across devices.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Makes me wonder what the strategy is behind introducing new themes that aren't for appcompat, when they have less available functionality than the support stuff that does require AppCompat.  Seems like the parts of Support Library that aren't explicitly for backwards compatibility (like RecyclerView, DrawerLayout,etc) should be useable with any new themes. Anyway, end of mini-rant, thanks again for your help

Answer (score 1):

Most of the Design Support Library, including `NavigationView`, requires use of AppCompat. You'll need to switch back to using `AppCompatActivity` and an AppCompat theme if you want to use the Design Library components.